# How to prevent MediaPlayer to start in other apps

Tags: android, audio, focus, android-audiomanager

I try to make simple mediaplayer app just for personal/educational purpose (play specific mp3 file) but i have a problem with others apps. I use services to play sound in background. Everything working fine but when i turn another media app i still can play simultaneously different song. How to "tell" to the system that my app is using mediaplayer and no ones can use mediaplayer till my services end. I use AudioManager STREAM_MUSIC and start playing my song when i get AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN checked by AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED.

to play my music and set the foreground notification i use

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

    if (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED == result) {

        this.startForeground();
        player.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use media players audio focus implementations, detail documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#audiofocus

Audio focus is one of the thing which assign to any application who request for that, means if you request for that, any other application using it will stop automatically & you;ll start using audio , same case while you are using it if any other app request for it, your audio will be stopped. You will be notifyed of the loss of audio focus through the **onAudioFocusChange handler** of the Audio Focus Change Listener you registered when requesting the audio focus

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

// Request audio focus for playback
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
// Use the music stream.
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
// Request permanent focus.
AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);


if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
// other app had stopped playing song now , so u can do u stuff now .
}
```

---

```
private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
          new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                  public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                             AudioManager am =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    switch (focusChange) {

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                           // Lower the volume while ducking.
                           mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                           break;
                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                           pause();
                           break;

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                           stop();
                           ComponentName component =new ComponentName(AudioPlayerActivity.this,MediaControlReceiver.class);
                           am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(component);
                           break;

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                           // Return the volume to normal and resume if paused.
                           mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                           mediaPlayer.start();
                           break;
                           default: break;
}
}
};
```

Comment: Thx for your reply but i looking for way to prevent others app to gain audiofocus while my app i running. When my app in on i want have audiofocus gain pernamently always untill i will turn off my app (if another app start using media  don't get audiofocus and don't change myaudiofocus)

Comment: Okay, I don't have any idea about that. As per my knowledge AudioFocus can't be held by one app with high priority. Because AudioFocus is used by notification also, As per your requirements, you want that no other app including Call or notification can use audioFocus. Even I would like to know the solution of this if any.
Please let me know if you found any solution.